# Camera moving along with the background out of sync in LIBGDX

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx

I have a sprite that I move around the world; it has its velocity increased based on a constant acceleration when the user touches the screen. I also move the camera with this sprite; but I also have a BG image that needs to stay still on the screen so the camera moves with the exact same velocity and acceleration as the background image so that it seems that the background is still. However, I see a slight out of sync between the camera and the background image; the background should stay still but it doesn't :

```
@Override
public void render () {
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        world_velocity += acceleration;
        back.setPosition(back.getX(), back.getY() + world_velocity);
        camera.position.y += world_velocity;    
        camera.update();
}
```

How can I sync the BG image with the camera so that the BG image stays still? NOTE : If I use constant velocity (no updates based on acceleration ) there is no issue.

Comment: Velocity and acceleration should be multiplied by `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` so they are not frame-rate dependent.  So `world_velocity += acceleration*deltaTime;` and `camera.position.y += world_velocity*deltaTime;`, etc. As for your issue, this might be a rounding problem. Although I also notice a typo `back.getY()` vs. `backs.getY()`. And you are setting the projection matrix before updating the camera, so the camera will lag by one frame. Regardless, I recommend using a separate camera for drawing your background.

Comment: Thank you! I'll update the code using your info . I'm sure it will be a welcomed update.

Comment: you can also simply render the background first with another, static camera